# Raspberry PI3B - Wireless USB mouse just partly working

Tags: wireless, mouse

So I've plugged in the reciever into one of the Raspberry's USB ports.

What is strange is that it responds to clicks, both the left and right button work. The scroll wheel also works.

However, it does **not** respond to any movement. It's a very lightweight, thin "Konig" mouse, optical.

It works fine on my PC. Any idèas?

Comment: Never mind. Figured it out.

Comment: Care to post your own answer if you found the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a battery problem.

The mouse takes two triple A batteries. One of them was a bit loose.

Oddly enough, it works fine on my laptop even with just one battery inserted, but on the PI, it needs both for it to fully function.